# Cross-account Route 53 editing using IAM Identity Center permissions

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-route53, amazon-policy

I'm trying to make changes to a Route 53 zone in one account (Account A), from a different AWS account (yep – Account B). The two accounts are in the same Organisation. We use [IAM Identity Center](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/identity-center/) to sign in (so not vanilla IAM).

I have edited the permission set for the Identity Center user, with an inline policy to allow access to the Route 53 hosted zone:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "route53:GetHostedZone",
                "route53:ChangeResourceRecordSets",
                "route53:ListResourceRecordSets"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:route53:::hostedzone/<zoneid>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, I keep getting permission denied errors:

```bash
% aws route53 get-hosted-zone --profile staging --id <zoneid>

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetHostedZone operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<account-b>:assumed-role/AWSReservedSSO_AdministratorAccess_<etc>/<identity-center-user> is not authorized to access this resource
```

I've checked the user is correct with `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile staging`.

The same request from my Identity Center user signed in to Account A (`aws route53 get-hosted-zone --profile develop --id <zoneid>`) works as it normally would, with a description of the zone.

As a sanity-check I also made a role in Account A to allow a trust relationship with the Identity Center user, and group, and account root, but still get the same error.

I've also tried the suggestions in [Assuming roles when logged in via IAM Identity Center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960189/assuming-roles-when-logged-in-via-iam-identity-center).

… which makes me wonder if there are some Route 53 wrinkles that make x-account access a bit trickier. AWS [seems to think](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/access-control-overview.html#access-control-resources) it should be doable though!

Will appreciate any guidance, thank you.